# Enabling ruby syntax highlighting for Emacs html.erb files

Tags: emacs

I am running Emacs Live with Rinari. In `.erb` files `html-mode` is enabled automatically, however embedded Ruby is not highlighted according to `ruby-mode`. Is there any way to enable both `html-mode` and `ruby-mode` within `.html.erb` files?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Check out [`web-mode`](http://web-mode.org/), which is designed for HTML templating. It can be installed via MELPA or Marmalade. (Note that this is not a way to run `html-mode` and `ruby-mode` simultaneously as you requested; it's a completely different mode. It's also probably your best bet.)

Out of the box, it supports `.html.erb` (and many others), with superficial CSS and JavaScript support (highlighting and indenting).

Comment: Sorry I am an emacs noob. When I add web-mode.el to ~/.emacs.d/lib and then add the code in install from http://web-mode.org/ into ~/.emacs.d/packs/live/bindings-pack, emacs live crashes upon reloading.

Comment: If you're using Emacs 24 or later (and it looks like Emacs Live requires this), I strongly recommend [using `package.el` to install Emacs packages](http://ergoemacs.org/emacs/emacs_package_system.html).

Answer (score 0):

Install 'rinari' for emacs which is specially for ROR. It has a mode called `eruby-nxhtml-mumamo-mode` which hightlights the html.erb syntax as we need. This [link](http://rinari.rubyforge.org/) will help you how to install it. It takes care of everything. Enjoy!

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.